# OpenMP parallel for with modulo operation

Tags: openmp

I'm just learning OpenMP and trying to parallelize the following construct:

```
for (r = 0; r <= (int)(N/2); r++)
{
    answer = ((answer % MOD) + (2 * (solve(N, r) % MOD)) % MOD) % MOD;
}
```

It seems to be natural to use reduction, but modulo operator is not supported for that case.

Also I tried to use private variables, but race conditions are still there:

```
#pragma omp parallel for private(temp)
for (r = 0; r <= (int)(N/2); r++)
{
    temp = answer;
answer = ((temp % MOD) + (2 * (solve(N, r) % MOD)) % MOD) % MOD;
}
```

Is there any way to get it work?
Thanks.

Comment: Looks like an algorithm that cannot be parallelized, because every loop depends on previous loop result. You cannot solve this problem by OpenMP syntax tricks. You need to convert this algorithm to another which can be parallelized, or this problem doesn't have solution.

Comment: @AlexFarber: this sort of dependency is amenable to parallelism, via the reduction pattern. I think that user-defined reduction in OpenMP 4.0 can do the job.

Comment: @AlexeyKukanov: the problem is that I must use Visual C++ which OpenMP version is 2.0.

Comment: "I must use VIsual C++ which only supports OpenMP 2.0" Well, you always have the option of buying a license for the Intel compiler for Windows, which supports modern OpenMP. (Complete disclaimer... I work for Intel on our OpenMP runtime :-))

Comment: @JimCownie, there is no need for that if the OP uses a little math: `reduction(+:answer)` works fine.  See my answer.

Comment: One also has the option of obtaining the mingw32 or another build of the FREE and modern GNU compiler for Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are restricted by whatever is possible with OpenMP 2.0, your way to go is writing a custom reduction. The basic scheme is:

- Before the parallel region, create an array for partial results. It should have at least as many elements as there are threads in the parallel region; you might use `omp_get_max_threads()` function which is the upper bound. Initialize it with zeros (the identity element for summation).
- Inside the parallel region, use `omp_get_thread_num()` function to obtain the number of the current thread within the parallel region, and use it as the index to the above array. Accumulate the result in the corresponding array element.
- After the region, use a serial loop to reduce the partial results accumulated in the array.

Comment: I made this way: 

`#pragma omp parallel for
for (r = 0; r <= (int)(N/2); r++)
    part_results[omp_get_thread_num()] = (part_results[omp_get_thread_num()] % MOD) + (2 * (solve(N, r) % MOD)) % MOD) % MOD;

for (r = 0; r < omp_get_max_threads() - 1; r++)
    answer = ((answer % MOD) + (part_results[r] % MOD)) % MOD;`

But it doesn't work.

Comment: @user144765: can you provide more information about how exactly the new code fails?

Comment: @AlexeyKukanov: race conditions: the answer is not the same as in sequential version.

Comment: @user144765: Then the code in `solve(N,r)` which is not shown is likely the culprit; the race condition, if any, must be there. Does it modify any global state?

Comment: @user144765 If I don't misinterpret the things that Alexey correctly pointed out in his previous comment, you can simplify the initial (serial) expression to `answer += 2 * (solve(N, r);` inside the loop and add `answer %= MOD;` immediately outside of the loop.

Comment: @AlexeyKukanov: surely not - solve(N,r) just reads from global array.
The full source is there - http://pastebin.com/0DVEcGbp

Comment: @Massimiliano: I will get overflow that way.

Comment: @Massimiliano: something wrong with your version: logic is not the same so the answer is wrong. I suppose the problem is with `r`:
`for (r = 0; r < omp_get_max_threads() - 1; r++)`. r must run over floor(N/2)...

Comment: @user144765: your code at pastebin has 2 bugs. One is that you did not initialize partial results with the identity element, i.e. 0. The other is in the loop condition `r < omp_get_max_threads() - 1;` - you both use strict inequality and subtract 1, so you do not include the last partial sum into the result.

Comment: @AlexeyKukanov: yes, indeed! I've fixed it and the answer is right now! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @user144765: I am glad to be of help. Since you are new to StackOverflow, let me share the link that explains what you should generally do when your question is answered: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: @Massimiliano, I just read your comments and realized that you already gave my answer in your comment " you can simplify the initial (serial) expression to answer += 2 * (solve(N, r); inside the loop and add answer %= MOD; immediately outside of the loop".

Comment: @Massimiliano, your suggestion for doing a custom reduction is not good.  It requires using run time libraries (e.g omp_get_num_threads()) and it likely will have false sharing do the array.  The false sharing can be fixed.  But a better solution is to create private versions of the sum and merge them in a critical section.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the property that [(x%a + y%a)%a = (x+y)%a](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/147140/what-are-the-properties-of-the-modulus).  Then

```
answer = ((answer % MOD) + (2 * (solve(N, r) % MOD)) % MOD) % MOD;
```

is the same as

```
answer = (answer + 2 * solve(N, r) % MOD) % MOD;
```

Over the sum you can show this is the same as

```
Sum(answer + 2 * solve(N, r) % MOD)%MOD
```

Therefore, all you need to do is this

```
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:answer)
for (r = 0; r <= (int)(N/2); r++)
{
    answer += 2 * solve(N, r) % MOD
}
answer%=MOD;
```

This could overflow for.  In that case you can do a custom reduction like this

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
    int answer_private = 0;
    #pragma omp for nowait
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        answer_private = ((answer_private % MOD) + (2 * (solve(N, r) % MOD)) % MOD) % MOD;
    }
    #pragma omp critical
    {
        answer = (answer%MOD + answer_private%MOD)%MOD; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Here is a working example proving that this is correct http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a73f4d94ae14dac9

Comment: @user144765, I updated my answer to handle overflow.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry, I don't have enough reputation to vote for your answer)

Comment: @user144765, did you test my custom reduction and did it work?